# SELECT MIN Date using WINDOW functions with additional row condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, group-by

For Table TT:

```
+----+------+-----------+------+
| ID | Name |   SDate   | Code |
+----+------+-----------+------+
|  1 | Ash  | 4/12/2016 | A    |
|  1 | Ash  | 4/19/2016 | A    |
|  1 | Ash  | 2/14/2016 | B    |
|  1 | Ash  | 1/1/2016  | A    |
|  2 | Brat | 9/21/2016 | A    |
|  2 | Brat | 8/7/2016  | A    |
|  2 | Brat | 8/19/2016 | B    |
|  2 | Brat | 11/21/2016| B    |
+----+------+-----------+------+
```

Preferably using Window functions (sub-query group by could also work if window doesn't),

I need to extract the earliest `SDate` for `Code= A` by each`ID` group, such that it's the **earliest** `SDate` after `Code=B`'s **earliest** `SDate`. Not before. So *Desired output* :

```
+----+------+-----------+
| ID | Name |   SDate   |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | Ash  | 4/12/2016 |
|  2 | Brat | 8/7/2016  |
+----+------+-----------+
```

Code Attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     TT.ID AS ID
    ,TT.Name AS Name
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN TT.Code='A' THEN TT.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY TT.ID) AS SDate

FROM TT
ORDER BY TT.ID
```

This gives me the earliest `SDate` for `Code=A` for each distinct ID, not the earliest after earliest `Code=B`

Comment: can there be more than one code=B for an id?

Comment: What is known about Code **B**? Is it always a single occurrence per name?

Comment: Yes. Good point. So earliest code=A after earliest code=B. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the minimum B date for each id and get the minimum A date after that date thereafter.

The expected result should have '9/21/2016' for Brat.

```
select id,name,min(sdate) from (
select id,name,code,SDate
,min(case when code='B' then sdate end) over(partition by id) as min_b_dt
 from tt) x
 where code = 'A' and sdate >=min_b_dt
 group by id,name
```

Comment: 8/7/16 would be earlier than 9/21/16

Comment: @AS91 *I need to extract the earliest SDate for Code= A by eachID group, such that it's the earliest SDate after Code=B's earliest SDate. Not before.* this is what the question says

Comment: Sorry if my wording was confusing. What I mean to ask is: For Brat, the earliest CodeB SDate is 8/19/16, and the earliest CodeA SDate after 8/19/16 would be 8/7/16. Hence 8/7/16. For Ashley, there's only one CodeB SDate so naturally 4/12/16 becomes the earliest CodeA SDate in the output.

Comment: @AS91 .. 8/7/2016 is before 8/19/16.. so the earliest A after 8/19/2016 should be 9/21/2016.

Comment: You got it. My bad. I didn't think Brat through and just considered the earliest A, partly owing to how I'd framed the question while ignoring this point initially. Thanks. Appreciate your patience.